# Fetch BigCommece Product Image URL

Tags: android, curl, imageview, bigcommerce

According to the documentation as provided by bigcommerce for the developer [LINK](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/products/images)

If we need to get the image of any product we need to hit the below url:

`products/id/images/id.json`

on which we get a response as below

```
{
"id": 116,
"product_id": 29,
"image_file": "p/022/astonishing-x-men-1-100k__36562.jpg",
"is_thumbnail": false,
"sort_order": 0,
"description": "",
"date_created": "Fri, 21 Dec 2012 18:54:04 +0000"
```

}

**BUT MY ISSUE IS**:
How to generate the final URL which will give me the image.
I tried appending the image_file to all possible combinations provided by the BigCommerce url.

Comment: I saw you post on a few other BigCommerce questions asking for help with this question. Please do not do that. If you need help and have not received a satisfactory answer please start a bounty on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is the solution.

Once you get the image_file, you just need to append your store_url along with product_images...So if we use the data that you provided in your question then the exact url to get the image will be

```
https://store_url/product_images/p/022/astonishing-x-men-1-100k__36562.jpg
```

Remember to replace store_url with your actual url. This worked for me. Let me know if it works for you or not. If it does not work then let me know and I will put up the exact code for ya...

cheers :)

Comment: This is it. Thank you Ahmad Nawaz bhai. Thankz alot, i spend my 5days in trying every possible base Url....You are a gem man! thank u thank u thank u....

Comment: You are welcome AabidMulani. I am glad that my answer helped you. Let me know if you need any other assistance regarding to BigCommerce API :)...

Comment: Ahmad Nawaz: I am building an android application for BigCommerse; I am aware that i cannot access the payment gateways by any means. Also i know that the cart in BC is been maintained locally. So i am planning to replicate the cart as in Web Scenario and store it in Mobile Cookies. And when the user clicks checkout then i will Redirect him to the BigCommerce Payment WebPage with this local cookies. IS THIS POSSIBLE? DO YOU HAVE ANY RESOURCE WHICH WILL HELP ME DOING THIS??? PLZ HELP!

Comment: honestly i could not completely pick the scenario you mentioned. Can you explain it a little more that what exactly you are looking for?

Let me know, Thanks :)

Comment: There is no Api call present to place the order on the BigCommerce server [WITH PAYMENT]. I asked the support and the replied as of now the have not provided any api calls for accessing their payment gateway in java. And they also mentioned in the web scenario the cart which holds the users selected products is maintained on the local machine.[i.e. Cookies] this cookie is then passed to the checkout page where the payment is done. So i am planing to maintain the cookies on the mobile. And when user clicks checkout i will hit the web Url for checkout. so IS THIS POSSIBLE?

Answer (score 0):

I think you append that to the URL for your store. So if your store is

```
https://store-xxx.mybigcommerce.com
```

then you use the URL

```
https://store-xxx.mybigcommerce.com/products/id/images/id.json
```

where you replace the first `id` with the product ID.

Comment: I tried this and did not help; BigCommerce web site store their images on the cdn2 servers which needs authentication and not directly accessible.Also their url keeps changing; So there has to be a common baseUrl for it [which is not mentioned in the documentation]. Any other method in your mind??

Comment: Of course, you need an authentication token as well. This stuff isn't free, you have to have an account.

Comment: You can also use their PHP API, it's in the documentation.

Comment: Ok, thank you; will explore and get something from that php code. As I am implementing it in Java application.

Comment: Nothing helpful out there :-(